# What tile types does vitalize upgrade, and to what tiles?

Tags: mods, civilization-4, fall-from-heaven-2

In Fall From Heaven 2 there is a spell called Vitalize that upgrades terrain.  However I've noticed it's not always available, and it doesn't tell you what you're upgrading the tile too.

**What tile types does vitalize upgrade, and to what tiles?**

Answer (score 4):

- ice to tundra
- tundra to plains
- desert to plains
- plains to grass land

[Source](http://fallfromheaven.wikia.com/wiki/Vitalize)

Comment: So just like in Civ 2 then.